# Hi everyone, I have some troubles running an easy sql query using pandasql

Tags: python, sqlite, pandasql

```
...
q='SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dTime) as hour FROM data'
output=pandasql.sqldf(q,globals())
```

(column dTime contains time-data as e.g. '2019-02-15 03:44:27')

It doesn't work due to this error:

OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error

I'm not able to understand how to solve it, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not support the function `extract()`, but you can use [`strftime()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
q = "SELECT strftime('%H', dTime) AS hour FROM data"
```

this returns the hour as a string in the format `hh`.

If you want the hour as a number, then:

```
q = "SELECT strftime('%H', dTime) + 0 AS hour FROM data"
```

By adding `0` to the result of `strftime()` it is implicitly converted to a number.